# I want to make a radio-like checkbox in VueJs

Tags: vue.js, checkbox, vuejs2

I want to make a radio-like checkbox in VueJs.

This is the code I have already written.
https://jsfiddle.net/WeiChienHsing/w4nxhLg2/

Since I am new to VueJs,I wonder whether there is a more concise way to accomplish this?

```
 <div id="div">
   <div v-for="(item,index) in items">
     <input type="checkbox" v-model="items[index]" v-on:click="chkEvent($event, index)" v-bind:id="'jslib' + (index + 1)" value="1" />
     <label v-bind:for="'jslib' + (index + 1)">{{ names[index] }}</label>
   </div>
 </div>
```

```
 new Vue({
   el: '#div',
   data: function() {
     return {
       items: new Array(5),
       names: ["VueJs", "ReactJs", "Angular", "jQuery", "BackBoneJs"]
     };
   },
   methods: {
     chkEvent: function(event, idx) {
       if (this.items[idx] == true) {
         event.preventDefault();
       }
       this.items.fill(false);
       this.items[idx] = true;
     }
   }
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
new Vue({
   el: '#div',
   data: function() {
     return {
       names: ["VueJs", "ReactJs", "Angular", "jQuery", "BackBoneJs"],
       selected: null
     };
   },
   methods: {
     handleSelection (item) {
      this.selected = item
     },
     checkSelection (item) {
      return item === this.selected
     }
   }
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="div">
   <div v-for="name in names">
     <input type="checkbox"
       @click="handleSelection(name)"
       :checked="checkSelection(name)" />
     <label v-bind:for="name">{{ name }}</label>
   </div>
 </div>
```

I think that you can better handle all of this without an array at all, look at the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/hqsw04m3/1/

This way you have direct access to the selected value, and you dont need to re-initialize your array every time

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this.

```js
 new Vue({
   el: '#div',
   data: function() {
     return {
       names: ["VueJs", "ReactJs", "Angular", "jQuery", "BackBoneJs"],
       selected: null
     };
   }
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
 <div id="div">
   <div v-for="name in names">
     <input type="checkbox"
       :id="name"
       @click="selected = name"
       :checked="selected === name" />
     <label v-bind:for="name">{{ name }}</label>
   </div>
 </div>
```